# If/then formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to created a formula in my spreadsheet in which if a certain cell has the text value of "enrolled" then the spreadsheet reflects the difference of two cells.  I entered this formula but it is incorrect.

```
=IF(B2="enrolled", R2-N2)
```

How do I fix this?
I also want to add into the formula if the text value is "waived" or "terminated" then the value will be "N/A"

Answer (score 3):

To put in the waived and terminated section use nested if statements

```
=IF(B2="enrolled", R2-N2,IF(OR(B2="waived",B2="terminated"),NA(),""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="enrolled",R2-N2,"")
```

The `IF` statement needs a value for both `FALSE` and `TRUE`. So the second parameter in this case would be the subtract function that you wish. The formula will place nothing into the cell if `B2="enrolled"` comes out `FALSE`, which is controlled by the third parameter.

So the `IF` statement goes: `=IF(LOGICAL_TEST,VALUE_IF_TRUE,VALUE_IF_FALSE)`

Comment: The only thing the OP was missing was the last comma (`,`) after the `R2-N2`. But you did a great job explaining how the formula works. That is what the community needs.

Comment: I entered this formula but it is coming out N/A even though the value of S2 is "Enrolled"   :       =IF(S2="enrolled", R2-N2, ("N/A"))

Comment: This should work: `=IF(S2="enrolled",R2-N2,"N/A")`

Comment: Both those work for me, check your spelling on what you entered in the cell.  Make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces (can use trim function)

Comment: That did it!  There was a trailing space.  Thanks so much Josh and gtwebb for your assistance!  :)